# Is there a way to hide the nth item in a list with CSS?

Tags: css

Example:

```
<ul class="mybuttons">
   <li class="mybutton"></li>
   <li class="mybutton"></li>
   <li class="mybutton"></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to hide the 2nd item using css?

Comment: Thanks for adding so much value to this question.

Comment: It matters because if you have the word "Designer" in your job title then you should ask the question at http://www.doctype.com. Otherwise the question is fine here at SO. I didn't just randomly ask it

Comment: Where are you getting my job title?

Comment: I'm not getting your job title from anywhere. That is exactly why I had to ask "What is your job title."

Comment: Wow.  That just goes to show how defensively I read things online.  Initially I read your comment as "your title supposes you should know the answer to this question, why the hell are you even asking?".  Sorry about that.
My title is CTO.  http://www.linkedin.com/in/jeremygollehon
This question was really for my personal website where I'm trying to simplify the UI of the Disqus comment system to relieve confusion for non-techie friends and family.  Disqus allows customization through CSS from their admin console. http://blog.thegollys.com/2009/09/testing-comments-again.html

Comment: P.S. - I initially flagged your comment and don't have the ability to remove the flag.  Not sure how it affects your rep., sorry.

Comment: Not a biggie. I'm sure it's not the first time I've been flagged and probably won't be the last. :)

Comment: In this case if you feel you are wearing a "Designer" hat for this question rather than a "Developer" hat, you could try the question at doctype.

Comment: But having said that I think the answer you got is certainly a good one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[nth-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) is indeed the CSS way.

In pure CSS, the syntax is simply

```
li.mybutton:nth-child(2){
   display:none;
}
```

`nth-of-type(2)` works in this case too.

Edit: Though this is the CSS answer, as noted, this is CSS3 and implemented [only in some browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html). IE and FF3 and below do not support this natively. Implemented in FF3.5, Konqueror, and incorrectly in Chrome, Safari, and Opera. `nth-of-type()` implementations are better.

Support in older browsers will require javascript (simplified with jQuery, et al). jQuery selector is described in the [Selectors/nthChild](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild) docs, and the above can be accomplished with `$("li.mybutton:nth-child(2)").hide()`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Bill. For the record this is a CSS3 implementation and, as Jon Galloway states, is only supported by 'modern' browsers.
http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#css3pseudoclasses

Comment: I don't think this is a real solution right now unless you can require your users to run the newest versions of non-IE browsers.

Comment: @Jon, it is a real solution to *his* question. He asked for CSS and tagged it css, so i gave him the CSS answer. But, i'll add a caveat to the answer.

Comment: bill - I agree, hope I didn't sound argumentative. Can't wait for wide browser support of CSS3!

Comment: @Jon, no, no worries. Yep! It will be nice when CSS3 is more widely adopted. Makes things *so* much easier.

Answer (score 9):

[n-th child pseudo selectors](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t39) do this, but they're not widely supported yet and won't be for a while. You'll either need Javascript / jQuery or to write out a special class for the items you want to hide or just hide the items directly.

Here's how you'd do it with jQuery:

```
$("ul.mybuttons li:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon.  To clarify...
JQuery has internal procedures that process CSS3 pseudo selectors passed as parameters thus making this solution back browser compatible? I only have access to the CSS for the purpose of this question but it's worth verifying my understanding for future projects.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, jQuery has a very advanced selector engine that handles CSS3+ and is backward compatible to IE6.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.mybuttons li:first-child {
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will first set up **the second li as class="hidden_li"** in the HTML file.

Example:

```
<ul class="mybuttons">
<li class="mybutton"></li>
<li class="mybutton" class="hidden_li"></li>
<li class="mybutton"></li>
</ul>
```

Then I will style it like this :

```
.hidden_li{
  visibility : hidden;
  height : 0px;
  width : 0px;
  margin : 0px;
  padding : 0px;
  overflow : hidden;
}
```

Comment: You killed the dead several times.